# I want to implement CircularProgressIndicator in my API Listing code, but where should I put it, any suggestions?

Tags: flutter, dart

Where should I implement the `CircularProgressIndicator` function? I am new in Flutter, here I need to show `circularprogressindicator` to show when `GestureDetector` is triggered, I tried various ways but it still does not work.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertest/controller/pdf_api.dart';
import 'package:fluttertest/view/announce_card.dart';
import 'package:fluttertest/view/pdf_viewer.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('REST API Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FetchDataWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FetchDataWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FetchDataWidgetState createState() => _FetchDataWidgetState();
}

class _FetchDataWidgetState extends State<FetchDataWidget> {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = {"message": []};
  List<dynamic> message = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // fetchData();
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchData() async {
    var headers = {
      'API-KEY': '(Confidential)',
      'Authorization':
          '(Confidential)'
    };
    var request =
        http.Request('GET', Uri.parse('http://vmo.nuboxtech.com/sfa-api/news'));
    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var raw = await response.stream.bytesToString();
      data = json.decode(raw);
      print(data);
      print("Data datatype: ${data.runtimeType}");
    } else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
    return data;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchData(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print("Has data: ${snapshot.requireData.toString()}");
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.requireData["message"].length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () async {
                    String pdf = snapshot.requireData["message"][index]['File'];
                    final url = pdf;
                    final file = await PDFApi.loadNetwork(url);
                    openPDF(context, file);
                  },
                  child: AnnounceCard(
                      title: snapshot.requireData["message"][index]['Title'],
                      theImage: snapshot.requireData["message"][index]
                          ['Image']),
                );
              },
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            print("Has error: ${snapshot.error}");
            return Container();
          } else {
            print("No data");
            return Container();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void openPDF(BuildContext context, File file) {
    Get.to(PDFViewerPage(
      file: file,
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code :

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              // While the data is being fetched, show the CircularProgressIndicator
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print("Has data: ${snapshot.requireData.toString()}");
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.requireData["message"].length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () async {
                      String pdf = snapshot.requireData["message"][index]['File'];
                      final url = pdf;
                      final file = await PDFApi.loadNetwork(url);
                      openPDF(context, file);
                    },
                    child: AnnounceCard(
                      title: snapshot.requireData["message"][index]['Title'],
                      theImage: snapshot.requireData["message"][index]['Image'],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              print("Has error: ${snapshot.error}");
              return Container();
            } else {
              print("No data");
              return Container();
            }
          },
```